# Despues de un tiempo se cierra la conexion a mi base de datos y mi programa deja de funcionar

Tags: java, mysql

Mi programa guarda un registro de ventas de brazaletes, y pasado cierto tiempo en uso del software en consola aparece una excepcion con el siguiente mensaje:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet
> successfully received from the server was 605.319.505 milliseconds
> ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 605.319.630
> milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of
> 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing
> connection validity before use in your application, increasing the
> server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J
> connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1364)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1349)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:384)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:802)

y el codigo de la clase que gestiona mi base de datos es la siguiente

```
public class DataBase_manager {

    private static final HikariDataSource dataSource;

    @Getter
    private static Connection connection;

    //Configuramos el pool de conexiones
    static {
        InputStream input = DataBase_manager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(properties);
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void saveBracelet(Brazalete[] brazalete) throws SQLException {
        String sql = getString(brazalete);

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        Arrays.stream(brazalete).forEach(b -> {
            try {
                if (b instanceof Brazalete_Propietario) {
                    setOwnerBracelet((Brazalete_Propietario) b, preparedStatement);
                } else if (b instanceof Brazalete_Invitado) {
                    setGuestBracelet((Brazalete_Invitado) b, preparedStatement);
                } else if (b instanceof Brazalete_alquilado) {
                    setRentedBracelet((Brazalete_alquilado) b, preparedStatement);
                }
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DataBase_manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        });

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();

    }
```

La excepcion sucede cuando se lleva alrededor de 20 minutos o menos y ya se produce la excepcion

Comment: Prueba con [`tcpKeepAlive=true`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-connp-props-networking.html).

Comment: Como hago eso?...

Comment: Agrega -por ejemplo- a tu archivo de propiedades Hikari `dataSource.keepaliveTime=600000`.